# Different types of interpolation used in computer vision

Tags: artificial-intelligence, computer-vision

[image: Known Image coordinate]

Known codition:

1. four pixels shown in the image $(i,j),(i+1,j),(i,j+1)$ and $(i+1,j+1)$
2. $a=0.9$ and $b=0.4$

I was able to calculate the **bilinear interpolation** using the algorithm provided by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation.

But how should we calculate the **Average Interpolation** and **Nearest Neighbor Interpolation**?

Comment: Use the algorithm for calculating these interpolations. After all, a computer can (and literally does) do that without applying the slightest bit of creativity.

Comment: Thanks, but I am having trouble finding the algorithm for the average interpolation.